# How do I use a python variable in sqlalchemy filter() function?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

How can I use a python variable in sqlalchemy filter() function like this?

```
dog_name=userinput()
```

#userinput()is a defined function `chosen_dog=session.query(Dog).filter(Dog.name==dog_name)`

Comment: Erm, exactly like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chosen_dog=session.query(Dog).filter_by(name = dog_name).one()
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer deals the issue.

Comment: When I answered it was different.You can pass dog_name in function  userinput(dog_name): chosen_dog=session.query(Dog).filter_by(name = dog_name).one() return chosen_dog

Answer (score 0):

just with `filter(Dog.name=dog_name)`